# Problemas na instalação do pacote RMySQL / Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Ao tentar instalar o pacote RMySQL usando a instrução:

```
install.packages('RMySQL')
```

Obtenho a seguinte informação de erro:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'RMySQL.so' failed
make: *** [RMySQL.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RMySQL’
* removing ‘/home/lepina/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/RMySQL’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status
```

Solicito ajuda, pois já desintalei e instalei o R, Já fiz um downgrade de versão da 4.0.0 para 3.6.3, porém nada resolve.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368708/cant-install-rmysql-on-r-3-0-2-ubuntu-14-04).